# Wu Hausman test to test for endogeneity

Tags: r, statistics

I have a model and I suspect endogeneity. I want to test whether this is the case with a Wu hausman test, though I can't find anywhere how to do this.

The following regression have been performed:

```
library(AER)
ivreg1 <- 
  ivreg(budget~ policyfactor+ control1 + control 2 | IV + control1 + control2, data=df)
```

```r
df <- data.frame(
        budget = c(10, 8, -7, 8, 3, 2, 0.5, 1.5, -2, -15, 30, -0.5, 12, 18),
  policyfactor = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L),
            IV = c(17L,46L,18L,23L,35L,10L,0L,19L,
                   15L,12L,21L,6L,27L,10L),
      control1 = c(29.4,27.4,33.2,27.1,27.4,34.2,
                   26.8,32.9,26,26.3,27.3,33.4,23.5,31.3),
      control2 = c(1.3,20,-0.2,3,3.4,0.3,-1.1,1.9,
                   -2,-1.6,2.8,1.9,2,1.8)
)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Have you seen this post?
https://bookdown.org/ccolonescu/RPoE4/random-regressors.html#specification-tests

Comment: See this R-bloggers [post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/an-ivreg2-function-for-r/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hausman test is available in the `summary` method using `diagnostics=TRUE` option.

```
summary(ivreg1, diagnostics=TRUE)
# Call:
#   AER::ivreg(formula = budget ~ policyfactor + control1 + control2 | 
#                IV + control1 + control2, data = df)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -18.292  -4.920  -1.719   4.057  23.612 
# 
# Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)   14.4933    31.2550   0.464    0.653
# policyfactor   1.2168    15.1335   0.080    0.938
# control1      -0.3945     0.9835  -0.401    0.697
# control2       0.5168     0.7209   0.717    0.490
# 
# Diagnostic tests:
#                  df1 df2 statistic p-value
# Weak instruments   1  10     2.211   0.168
# Wu-Hausman         1   9     0.944   0.357            <--- THERE IT IS!
# Sargan             0  NA        NA      NA
# 
# Residual standard error: 11.46 on 10 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-Squared: 0.1545,   Adjusted R-squared: -0.09916 
# Wald test: 0.381 on 3 and 10 DF,  p-value: 0.769
```

Comment: Thank you, that is really simple! And then the p-value says whether there is endogeneity or not?  So, lower than 0.05 there is no endogeneity?

Comment: Life is not a dichotomy between p < 0.05 and p > 0.05.  :)  Was your experiment designed to detect endogeneity?  What do other diagnostics report?  Apply thought, reach a justifiable conclusion.

Comment: @es_dutch The p-value of the Hausman test indicates the probability that your predictor `policyfactor` is correlated with the residuals. Since it's above your significance level of 0.05, you want to _reject_ the null hypothesis that there is _no_ endogeneity, i.e. you have endogeneity.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your clear answer. But do you need to check this with the IV regression or the normal regression? I think the normal regression lm(budget~policyfactor+control1+control2). 

Edit: I tried this but it doesnt work with LM. I thought you could check with the LM whether you need to do IV or not.

Comment: @es_dutch Good question! I think you need both, OLS and IV for comparison, which is done internally in `ivreg`.

Comment: @es_dutch There's no such option for `lm`. When you call `summary`, R automatically chooses an appropriate [method](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#s3-methods) for the class of the object, and `summary.ivreg` is only called for class `"ivreg"` objects.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers.
@Limey, I don't have an experiment. There is self-selection as the municipalities choose their own policies. I have trouble finding a good IV. Nothing I did works..